# Convert-tabs-to-spaces Button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

There are many questions on Stack Overflow with **bad code formatting** or **wrong indentation**.

Usually this requires some work to fix when reviewing a question. Especially, when someone has a lot of code, and used tabs instead of spaces.

Most of the time, I end up cutting out the code, inserting it into an editor, and pressing "*Convert tabs to spaces*". Afterwards it's easy to insert the code, and press the <kbd>{ }</kbd>-button to provide correct indentation and highlighting.

**Providing correct indentation and better code formatting might be much easier, if Stack Overflow automatically converted tabs to spaces when inserting code.**

Optionally, a <kbd>Tabs to spaces</kbd> button in the editor can provide the same functionality, without harming tab-sensitive languages.

Are there any reasons why this feature isn't already available?

Comment: there are [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/improvements-to-editor-for-formatting-source-code), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar) or [a couple of other suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editor) on that...

Comment: And then we have Balpha that provided a userscript: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts

Comment: @rene Thanks, this extension is awesome. However, I think that adding this functionality to SO would be worth the work.

Comment: [Give it 6-8 weeks...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100)

Comment: Python.  You get a few people that don't understand just *how important* whitespace is in Python to review and "fix" the indentation, and you've got a mess on your hands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Literal tab in code block renders as four spaces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403016/literal-tab-in-code-block-renders-as-four-spaces) It appears that the feature was implemented at some point.

Comment: How can a 9 year old question suddenly become a duplicate of a 2 year old question?

Comment: @maja the direction of the duplicate isn't as important as directing users to the most useful set of answers. (it's also not possible to close a question as a duplicate of another without an upvoted answer)