# Literal tab in code block renders as four spaces

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I *think* this used to work correctly before because I have memories of testing this when responding to [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) questions before, where proper tabs are crucial. (That would have been before the [switch to CommonMark.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark))

But at least as of last night, [putting a literal tab in a code block in an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920002/874188) no longer works, and instead produces four spaces.

(My answer initially had  ```` ```make ```` but I changed it to  ```` ```makefile ```` in accordance with the [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355638/syntax-highlighting-faq-list-updates); but this didn't seem to matter.)

This means the code can no longer be correctly copy/pasted by visitors to the site.  Could this please be changed (back, I assume)?

Comment: A Meta request to make copy-pasta easier getting upvotes? What is happening?!

Comment: Apart from `makefile`, what other tools/languages require use of TAB character?

Comment: Tangentially, filed https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2883

Comment: @Abra [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) for one!

Comment: Python indentation errors can be hidden by such a silent conversion. It used to be possible to detect these by inspecting the contents of a code block.

Comment: This conversion ***for rendering*** has *always* been there (from the very beginning or at the very least since early 2009). The TABs are preserved and are available for copy-pasting in the `source` view from the revision history (and during editing).

Comment: [`source` view](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9b3766f3-0474-4953-aa07-494c97450690/view-source) for your example. The TABs are preserved (and ***not*** converted when saved) and can be copy-pasted from that page (and during editing). They are only converted for rendering purposes (a sort of caching?).

Comment: Aside from rendering as four spaces in the post, the tab will appear as a single character in the text field if you try to edit the post - but one which happens to be four spaces wide.

Answer (score 5):

I'm confused and saddened by the staff response here, and would like to urge reconsideration.

#### Accuracy is more important than uniformity

> This way we can guarantee that whitespace in our code snippets is consistent and uniform.

Programmers expect their tools not to lie to them. Debugging problems often requires a representation of data that is as raw and literal as possible, so that things that are out of place can be *seen*, where a "friendlier" representation might obscure the difference. Making things look nice is the job of editors.

Whether it's because tabs must be used consistently (as with Makefiles), cause problems when mixed with spaces (Python), or are distinct from spaces and must be used carefully to communicate the program (Whitespace), being able to distinguish tabs from spaces **matters**. Converting to either spaces or tabs **loses information**. If there is supposed to be a mixture for whatever reason, you can't get it back after conversion.

There are [actual questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083417/python-nameerror-name-self-is-not-defined-why) on Stack Overflow where diagnosing the problem depends on recognizing the indentation for what it actually is, and currently we can only see this in the raw source. Even if someone comes along and finds the problem that way, the result looks confusing for people who arrive later, perhaps via a search engine. (After all, nothing is amiss in the code actually shown on the page, even if you select the whitespace).

It should be easy enough to preserve the tabs, and also background-shade them, by putting them into a `span` that applies the appropriate CSS. (After all, the syntax highlighting already works this way.) They could be shaded even if they *are* converted (since each tab will directly correspond to *at least one* space).

#### What's actually most convenient?

> You're right that this makes things for Makefile samples harder when it comes to copy/pasting. I recommend adding an explicit explanation that readers should use tabs, not spaces, when writing a `make` snippet.... It's... to make... copy/pasting... a little more pleasant by presenting something that's consistent. You'd be surprised how many code snippets we see that include a wild mix of tabs and spaces.

This is self-contradictory. Aside from my personal distaste for encouraging copy and paste (though nothing can really be done about that), the change that is supposed to make things "more pleasant" is *actively a hindrance* [in possibly tens of thousands of cases](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmakefile%5D+is%3Aa&searchOn=3) (hat tip to the OP). Everyone expects web pages to offer "copy to clipboard" buttons nowadays anyway; that would be a fine spot to add "and normalize indentation while you're at it" logic, while people who want the verbatim text can use the browser's built-in copy and paste.

For that matter, people who *are* prone to copying and pasting will probably be copying and pasting *into an IDE* (well... not for Makefiles, probably), which will happily reformat the text anyway (along with adding extra indentation appropriate to the context where it's pasted).

Comment: Just ran into the issue again [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909643).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug, it's a feature™

As soon as you save a question, we normalize whitespace in code blocks. All tabs get turned into spaces. This way we can guarantee that whitespace in our code snippets is consistent and uniform. This behavior didn't change with the migration to CommonMark, we've done this kind of heresy before.

You're right that this makes things for `Makefile` samples harder when it comes to copy/pasting. I recommend adding an explicit explanation that readers should use tabs, not spaces, when writing a `make` snippet. Even if we didn't do this kind of normalization, this would be a good addition as you never know whether readers copy/paste or type out your code snippet and mistake your tabs for spaces.

Be assured, this is not part of a bigger plot to finally settle the *tabs vs spaces* discussion. It's more a pragmatic decision to make everyone's favorite pastime, copy/pasting from Stack Overflow, a little more pleasant by presenting something that's consistent. You'd be surprised how many code snippets we see that include a wild mix of tabs *and* spaces.

*Edit*: As Peter Mortensen rightly pointed out (sorry, my explanation was too sloppy): converting tabs to spaces happens when we convert your post from Markdown to HTML. This happens once whenever you change your post. We store the rendered HTML and serve that when users are viewing your post. Your original Markdown will remain unchanged.

Comment: So are you proposing that [all these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmakefile%5D+is%3Aa&searchOn=3) (currently, 29,566 of them) should be edited with a boilerplate explanation of how it's a feature that the code as displayed doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not. Apparently this hasn't been a problem for those 29k answers. I'm merely suggesting that you could include an explanation if you feel there's ambiguity without it.

Comment: @PM2Ring we are respecting tab stops when converting tabs to spaces

Comment: That's excellent news. :)

Comment: Tabs *definitely* used to be preserved in the source (e.g. copy-pasting from the "source" view in the revision history). When did that change?

Comment: The TABs are preserved, even if editing now. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5e86bd74-ab10-42be-af1c-becf5f9f4869/view-source). From [ID 6473952](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/how-can-i-create-a-memory-leak-in-java/6473952#6473952).

Comment: Are TABs now converted when creating *new* posts?

Comment: [The answer posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919597/makefile-logical-and/64920002#64920002) was not converted (the TABs are preserved).

Comment: Re *"All tabs get turned into spaces"*: But only for rendering purposes (caching/prepared output), not the primary storage(?). Can you make that more clear in your answer?